# Required permissions for azure-spatial-anchors in Android

Tags: android, azure-spatial-anchors

I have installed the official [Android sample for Azure Spatial Anchors](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/tree/master/Android).

The sample requires, among others, the following permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Are they all really required? What for?

Answer (score 3):

I believe those permissions are necessary when capturing diagnostics. If you're not capturing diagnostics, then they're probably not necessary. You can see the required permissions in the [Android app tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-new-android-app).